# Twilio authentication on AWS Lambda with Node.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, aws-lambda, twilio

I want to authenticate with Twilio's api using the Node.js https module. My code is essentially:

```
const options = {
    host: 'api.twilio.com',
    path: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + TWILIO_ACCOUNT + '/Messages.json',
    auth: {
        user: TWILIO_ACCOUNT,
        pass: TWILIO_API_KEY
    }
};

const req = https.get(options, (res) => { ...
```

The error I receive is `TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object`. If I remove the `auth` argument in the options:

```
const options = {
    host: 'api.twilio.com',
    path: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + TWILIO_ACCOUNT + '/Messages.json'
};

const req = https.get(options, (res) => { ...
```

the error I receive is `Authentication Error - No credentials provided`. This leads me to believe I am not passing the authentication correctly in the options.

( Using `request-promise`, this method of passing the authentication works; I was trying to see if I could get it to work using a Node.js built-in module )

Comment: Why don't you use twilio npm?

Comment: @Shaharyar - as an challenge, to see if I can do this only using built-in modules

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The `auth` property in the `options` object requires that its value is a `string` (see [the options you can use here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)).

So, to correct your `options` object, you need to concatenate the Account SID and Auth Token with a colon, like this:

```
const options = {
  host: 'api.twilio.com',
  path: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + TWILIO_ACCOUNT + '/Messages.json',
  auth: `${TWILIO_ACCOUNT}:${TWILIO_API_KEY}`
}
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: This works.  Would be helpful if it was clearer in the Twilio docs.

Comment: The Twilio docs are about the Twilio Node module which we provide to make this easier. This particular detail is only relevant if you are using the Node.js HTTP standard library module and is [documented there](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback).